# bash alias doesn't work properly

Tags: terminal, git-bash, bash

Following is my ".bash_profile" on mac

```
alias status='git status'
alias cdp='cd ~/cdp/'
alias test='cd ~/test/'
```

Problem is if I don't add space after each command it doesn't run properly:-

`$status` returns following on my git repo:

> ' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
>
> Did you mean this?    status

`$cdp` returns

> : No such file or directory/

`$test` runs fine

After I add additional space after each alias (except the last one) it works fine but while launching terminal or `$source ~/bash_profile` it gives following errors:

> : not founds:
>   : not founds:

Comment: Just ion case, did you check your eol (end of line character), just to make sure they are LF, not CRLF?

Comment: Awesome, that was causing the issue. Can you please post it as answer I"ll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all aliases fail except for the last line, that suggests an eol (end of line character) issue.

Make sure all lines end with LF, not CRLF.